# Объясните, почему данном примере при n = 3 на выходе не будет ошибки

Tags: c, пузырьковая-сортировка

Это не очень серьёзный вопрос, поэтому минусите, если хотите. Но объясните, мне идиоту, почему в этой пузырьковой сортировке при n = 3 нет ошибки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main()
{
    int n = GetInt();
    int cash[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cash[i] = GetInt();
    int normal = 0;
    do{
    normal++;
    for (int j = 0; j<n; j++){      
        if(cash[j] > cash[j+1]){
            int s = cash[j+1];
            cash[j+1] = cash[j];
            cash[j] = s;
            normal = 0;
        }
    }
    }while(normal != 1);
    for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        printf("%i,", cash[j]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Да, в строке:

`for (int j = 0; j<n; j++){`

есть ошибка, при 
    `j<n`
 будет выход за пределы массива. Но, при n=3 ошибки нету. Почему?

Comment: скорее всего, потому что память редко выделяется точно, как попросят, обычно она округляется до кратного 16. При трех int нужно 12 байт. И ещё 4 остается:) если я прав, то подобное будет и для 7.

Comment: Ошибка есть. Она не проявляется, если в cash[n] какое-то большое число. А вы что ожидали увидеть?

Comment: А какую ошибку вы хотите получить, выйдя за границу массива? Думаете, что при выходе за границу массива программа аварийно завершиться или как-то сообщит вам, что произошёл выход за границу? Может и сообщит, а может и нет. Вот такие они коварные массивы :)

Comment: @KoVadim, практически в любом доступном студенту случае  память в стеке будет валидной. По крайней мере main-у надо же где-то сохранить несколько регистров...

Comment: это все понятно - когда заходим в область UB, там может случиться все что угодно.

Comment: @KoVadim, возможно, но соль в том, что при n = 3, сортировка проводится корректно, при 7 я не пробовал, но если и при 7 всё работает, то это всё очень странно, так как мне не что в этих 4 байтах, если сортировка проводится корректно.

Comment: Если в этих последних 4 байтах находится 0x7fffffff, то ничего удивительного. С другой стороны, если Вы вводите маленькие числа, а сортировка по возрастанию, то там миллионы подходящих значений. Главное, чтобы было больше.